# laravel 4 using wildcards in the url for routes spanning arbitrary sub-directories

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have a route:

`Route::get('/{slug}c{id}','Category@index');`

which works for http://domain.tld/arbitrarycategory-c22

but I'd like to make a wildcard route that matches any arbitrary sub directory as well. My controller only cares about the -c{id} portion of the route, anything before that is arbitrary and ignored. I'm looking for one route that would match these two:

```
http://domain.tld/arbitrarycategory-c22
http://domain.tld/parentcategory/childcategory/category-c22
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How many levels of categories do you need?

Comment: just two, a root level category and a sub-category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom route model binding :)

```
<?php
Route::get('{parentCategory}/...', 'controller@method');
```

And bind 'parentCategory' to the route, see: http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-model-binding. And add some more bindings for more layers.